# How should I deposit money in my bank account for the UK study visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, study, financial

I would like to know how should I deposit money in my bank account to provide it as a financial proof for UK study visa.

I should deposit around 18000£. This money was donated to me by my parents and grandmother, and I worked on my own. Should I declare where I got this money when I deposit it in my bank account, or at the embassy?

Comment: If that amount of money suddenly appears in your bank account then alarm bells are going to ring. You must provide a convincing explanation of where it came from and why.

Comment: Are the funds still in your parents' account or are in cash waiting to be deposited to your account? UKVI is used to seeing Students using their parents' funds, and routinely accepts (parents' bank account statement + parents' statement of consent to money being used) as evidence (see [guidance from UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/financial-evidence-for-student-and-child-student-route-applicants) and [guidance form a UK uni](https://documents.manchester.ac.uk/display.aspx?DocID=28713)).

Comment: See the [Travel.SE] tag [proof-provenance-of-funds](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-provenance-of-funds).

Comment: While a few years old, Gayot Fow's Answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) may also assist you in seeing how UKVI looks at this issue.